# Failed to launch debug adapter locally when changing ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, iis-express

I have a solution with a pretty standard config structure

```
appsettings.json
   appsettings.Development.json
   appsettings.Testing.json
   appsettings.Production.json
```

`Testing` and `Production` servers have an `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `Testing` and `Production` respectively and the everything works, proper config get's chosen, etc.

I wanted to load `appsettings.Testing.json` in my local Visual Studio so I went to my `launchSettings.json` and changed `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Testing` and Studio throws the error on launch.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:28725",
      "sslPort": 44342
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Testing"  <- was "Development"
      },
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    }
  }
}
```

Just to summarize all I did was changed that one setting from `Testing` to `Development` and Studio throws the `Failed to launch debug adapter` error upon launching.

And that's kinda it, nothing in the output windows, nothing in the windows eventviewer that I could find.

Comment: `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` can be set to any value, but three values are supported by the framework: `Development`, `Staging`, and `Production`. If no value is set, it will default to `Production`. So when you set to `Testing` it should default to `Production`.

Comment: Can you be specific about how you set up your environment? I did not reproduce your problem. Maybe [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0) can help you.